# Best .net web hoster for high traffic website

Tags: web-hosting, high-volume

Hi developing an idea which we expect if delievered correctly can develop into high volume website. What good .net web hosting companies do you recommend? If cost is required for high quality of service, no problem, throw the ideas out there please.

Thanks in adavnce

Answer (score 1):

Azure, Amazon EC2, sounds like you should be using the benefits of the public cloud and elastic computing.  All of which can scale to support your application/website dynamically so you only pay for what you use.